# Ошибка ajax запроса - parsererror

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

У нас есть неболшой html код:

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*">
<a href="#" class="submit button">Загрузить файлы</a>
```

Через ajax отправляю собраные картинки для обработки

```
 let files;

$('input[type=file]').change(function(){
    files = this.files;
    if(files.length == 8){
        $('.erroResponse').hide();
    } else {
        $('.erroResponse').show();
    }
});

$('.submit.button').click(function( event ){
    event.stopPropagation(); // Остановка происходящего
    event.preventDefault();  // Полная остановка происходящего

    // Содадим данные формы и добавим в них данные файлов из files
    var data = new FormData();
    $.each( files, function( key, value ){
        data.append( key, value );
    });
    // Отправляем запрос
    $.ajax({
        url: '/acces/default/loadimage.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function( respond, textStatus, jqXHR ){

            if( typeof respond.error === 'undefined' ){
                // Файлы успешно загружены, делаем что нибудь здесь
                str = respond.replace(/\]\[/g, ",");
                var data = JSON.parse(str);
                console.log(data);
            }
            else{
                console.log('ОШИБКИ ОТВЕТА сервера: ' + respond.error );
            }
        },
        error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
            console.log('ОШИБКИ AJAX запроса: ' + textStatus );
        }
    });

});
```

В результате получаю ошибку: parsererror;
 dataType: меняю на jsonp - таже ошибка;
 dataType: меняю на text получаю другую ошибку -

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

Comment: так вы напечатайте в консоль содержимое str перед parse и посмотрите что в нем не корректного ? потому что у ошибки единственное объяснение - то что вам пришло на вход json не является. хотя учитывая что ошибка в том что конец в самом начале можно заподозрить что в str вообще ничего нет

Comment: вывести в консоль дату? или я чето не понял на щет str

Comment: `console.log(respond);`

Comment: ReferenceError: respond is not defined

Comment: напишите строчку `console.log(respond);` сразу после `success: function( respond, textStatus, jqXHR ){`

Comment: Ответ приходит как error, а не success.Тоесть срабативает 
error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
            console.log('ОШИБКИ AJAX запроса: ' + textStatus );
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите строчку

```
dataType: "json",
```

или замените ее на

```
dataType: "text",
```

Ваш ответ от сервера не соответствует формату JSON.

Comment: repsond пустой приходит и выдает ошибку:
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: @JuniorCoder Мы догадывались ). Собственно, теперь Вы знаете в чем дело.

Comment: Понял, в чем может быть трабл, в самом php коде?

Comment: @JuniorCoder Да. В том, как код на сервере формирует ответ.